# Why can't root write into `/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/` on macOS Catalina and newer

Tags: macos, permissions

I'm trying to understand why on macOS (Catalina to Ventura) user `root` (i.e., me after `sudo bash`) gets

```
# mkdir /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/foo
mkdir: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/foo: Operation not permitted
```

whereas

```
# mkdir /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/Logging/foo
```

in a sibling directory with apparently identical file permissions and location works fine.

Note that:

- the error given is `Operation not permitted` and not `Read-only file system` or `Permission denied`, so this appears to have nothing to do with access-control permissions or the read-only mounting of the root filesystem.
- `/System/Volumes/Data/` is a writeable volume.
- These two folders look very similar with `ls -ldOe`, `xattr`, and `stat -r`

```
    # cd /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/
    # ls -ldOe Logging OpenDirectory
    drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  - 128 22 Aug 17:54 Logging
    drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  - 160 17 Aug 16:13 OpenDirectory
```

- Neither folder is listed in `/usr/share/firmlinks` or `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf`

The `mkdir` operation *does* work after I disable *System Integrity Protection*, so that clearly plays a role, but how?

How can I see which folder is affected by SIP being enabled?

How can system tools such as `sudo dsconfigldap -a ldap-server.example.com` still write there?

P.S.: The actual problem I originally wanted to solve is the same as described at

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378051/automated-ldap-and-search-setup-on-catalina
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250962320

But now I also simply want to understand how macOS actually prevents write access for root here, as I can't see any of the access-control mechanisms that I am familiar with appearing to play a role here: file permissions, extended ACLs, read-only mounting, SIP, file locking, firmlinks, etc. What makes these two folders different?

Comment: The system volume is signed & sealed, inviolable. Here's a good history of how that came about - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379#193379

Comment: But these folders appear to be on the `Data` volume, which is not signed and sealed, and which is meant to be writeable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not within reach of a newer Mac right now to double-check this - most of the Macs here are intentionally held on Mojave, where you're still in charge of your own destiny;) `/System` isn't on an unprotected volume, no matter how the Mac masks actual locations to the user. `~/Library` is where you need to be.

Comment: @Tetsujin `/System/Volumes/Data` is the mount point for the writable "Data" volume, not part of the sealed system volume. Also, you can't make changes to the OD bindings and search policy in the user library.

Comment: `/System/Volumes/Data/Library` is the same directory as `/Library`, with the same protections. That also goes for Applications, Users, and private,

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess is that it's being restricted by the privacy protection system ("Transparency, Consent, and Control" aka TCC), which is implemented via SIP but has separate policies. TCC was added in 10.14 (Mojave), but expanded significantly in 10.15 (Catalina). As for the original problem: does the `dsconfigldap` command still work?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, `dsconfigldap -a ldap-server.example.com` still creates a new file `/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/ldap-server.example.com.plist`, which root can't do there.

Comment: @MarkReed Since `/Library` is just a firmlink defined in `/usr/share/firmlinks` leading to `/System/Volume/Data/Library`, I didn't even mention the former in the question.

Comment: you're right, I had it backwards. /Library is writable precisely because it's just a firmlink into /System/Volume/Data. Sorry, no help.